# How make a Model validation on multiple methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, callback

I want to check if my entity attributes are between 0 and 5 on `:create` and `:update`. So I add a validation like this in my model :

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_attribute, :second_attribute

  validate :check_attributes, on: :create and :update

  private

  def check_attributes
    if self.first_attribute < 0 || self.first_attribute> 5
      errors.add(:first_attribute, "first_attribute must be between 0 and 5")
    end
    if self.second_attribute < 0 || self.second_attribute > 5
      errors.add(:second_attribute , "second_attribute must be between 0 and 5")
    end
  end

end
```

It works on creation : when I try to create an entity like `MyObject.create!(first_attribute: 7, second_attribute: 4)` I get an error. And if I put a value between 0 and 5, it creates the entity.

But when I update an existing entity like `my_entity.update_attributes!(first_attribute: 7)` it permits the update because it doesn't go in the validate function.

**How can I make it works on both methods (create and update) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line should read

```
validate :check_attributes, on: [:create, :update]
```

But instead you could also use the builtin validations. Also `:create` and `:update` are the default value for `on`, so you could also omit it:

```
validates :first_attribute,
          inclusion: { in: 0..5, message: "must be between 0  and 5" },
validates :second_attribute,
          inclusion: { in: 0..5, message: "must be between 0  and 5" },
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Rails validations run for both `create` and `update`. So it should be just:

```
validate :check_attributes
```

See the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) for this.

You should use `:on` option only if you want to validate either for `create` or `update`. But, if you want to do the validation for both, you don't need to specify the `:on` option. By default, Rails will do the validation for both.

But, there are better ways of validating attributes that are between 0 and 5. You can use [Rails inclusion helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) to do this rather than defining your own custom validators.

```
validates :first_attribute,
          inclusion: { in: 0..5, message: "first_attribute  must be between 0 and 5" },
validates :second_attribute,
          inclusion: { in: 0..5, message: "second_attribute  must be between 0 and 5" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
validate :check_attributes, :on => [:create, :update]
```

With this the validation will only run in the create and update actions.
Here's the link to the [apidocs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate).